# API call to Pre Fill DocuSign Template does not work

Tags: json, docusignapi, powerform

I want to prepopulate a DocuSign Template that has a PowerForm.The ApplicantName and ApplicanSSN numbers are the mandatory fields that needs to be pre-filled. I am using the following code to test in Postman. The envelope is being sent, but the data is not populating. Are PowerForms populated in a different way with an API call? I understand if the data is prepopulating there is no need for those template tabs to be mandatory. But this is just for testing. So can this be an issue for data not populating?Is it necessary to remove this mandatory field's properties before I do an API call?Can anyone please help me with this problem?

```
{
"accountId": "12345",
"emailSubject": "DocuSign Signature Request from Template",
"templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "sally.doe@email.com",
        "name": "Sally Doe",
        "roleName": "Employee",
        "tabs": {
            "textTabs": [
                {
                    "tabLabel": "ApplicantName",
                    "value": "Sally Doe"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "ApplicantSSN",
                    "value": "12-345-6789"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"status": "sent"
```

}

Comment: Can anyone Please tell me what am I doing wrong in prefilling my template ?Above is my code and explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerForms aren't typically populated via the API - This is envelope creation using a template.

Vocabulary aside, you'll want to confirm your template ID is correct. If the ID is correct, it's likely that you're not mapping your recipient correctly. Does the Role Name in the template exactly match the RoleName parameter in your API call?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have checked the Template ID and RoleName.Both are correct. Only the issue is I have 2 recipients with same roleName i.e 'Employee'.One is a signer and other is who receives Carbon Copy.So do I have to use Signer [ ] ,before template Roles?

Comment: Thanks, I used   GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients?include_tabs=true to get the exact name of the labels and found out I was using wrong label names.